# not able to write in firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
  exports.sendBigQueryData = 
  functions.analytics.event('buy_from_shop').onLog((event) => {
  const bigQuery = bigquery({ projectId:  });
  bigQuery.query({
  query: 'select email from table',
  useLegacySql: false
        }).then(function (results) {
        console.log(results);
        var ref = admin.database().ref("BigQueryData");// this should 
       //create a node with name BigQueryData and store the emails 
            there!

        var rows = results[0]; //get all fetched table rows
         rows.forEach(function(row){ //iterate through each row
            ref.push().set({ 
                email:row['email']


            });
        });
        //return result
    });
     {
      console.log(email,points);
      return 0;
       }
  });
```

I m trying to add the email in firebase realtime db but not able to.
can anyone help me to make this correct?

Comment: Can you show the error that you are getting

Comment: not getting anything in logs @mark922

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work. Within a Cloud Function triggered by a background event you must return a promise (or in certain cases a value, e.g. `return false;`).

In addition, since you are writing several times in the database with `forEach()`, you cannot use the `set()` method several times at the same reference because you will overwrite each previous write. You should use the `update()` method (doc is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields)).

```
  exports.sendBigQueryData = 
  functions.analytics.event('buy_from_shop').onLog((event) => {
      const bigQuery = bigquery({ projectId:  });

      return bigQuery.query({   // <- here add a return
        query: 'select email from table',
         useLegacySql: false

      }).then(function (results) {
         console.log(results);
         //.....

         let updates = {};

         const rows = results[0]; //get all fetched table rows
         rows.forEach(function(row){ //iterate through each row
            const newPostKey = admin.database().ref().child('BigQueryData').push().key;

            updates['/BigQueryData/' + newPostKey] = {email:row['email']};
        });

        return admin.database().ref().update(updates); // <- we return a promise

    }).catch(function (err) { // <- You have to catch the possible errors as well
       console.log(err);  
    });
  });
```

---

Finally, I would suggest you watch the following two videos from the Firebase team which detail how Cloud Functions shall be written, and in particular the fact that you must return promises:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk

The first one is more about HTTP Functions that are triggered through an HTTP request (so not with a background event) while the second is focused on background event triggered Functions, but it is advised to watch the first one before watching the second one.